# InValid CAN packets Observed RPI 3B+

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3, can-bus

RPI 3B+ connected with HAT consisting of CAN Transceiver. CAN interface is enabled and configured and link is UP. I'm using bus.send(msg) and bus.recv() functions to transmit and receive can packets. RPI is connected to another device to which handles CAN packets.

overview as below,

bus = can.interface.Bus(channel="can1", bustype="socketcan", bitrate=1000000)

msg = ID with DATA

bus.send(msg) is working fine.
bus.recv() is not working. Meaning, Invalid packets with CAN ID and data are seen  when debug print is put at bus.recv() (response = bus.recv() print(respose)). When removed CAN connection between device and RPI, these invalid packets are observed.
I don't understand, from where RPI is reading this invalid CAN packets (packet has ID,DLC  and data ). Let me know anyone faced such issue and solution if you have any,
Thank you

Comment: Check your bus termination, at that baud it is critical.

Comment: Okay. bus.recv() is not working properly. Where as CAN case works fine. No invalid packets are observed. RPI reading cyclic messages at every 400ms

Comment: bus.recv() is read in a loop and reads the same value. Any solution will be appreciated. thanks. With Termination also did not work

Comment: Can we read the CAN bus using bus.recv() function continuously ?